# Generating classes from Avro schema that includes java core package's classes : How to use those fields properly?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, avro

Assuming this java class :

```
public class Status {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Point position;
}
```

With `Point position` being the object from `java.awt.Point` (a java core package class), you can serialize it producing this schema :

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Status",
  "namespace": "com.example.entities",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "position",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Point",
        "namespace": "java.awt",
        "fields": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when deserializing this schema to generate classes (using the avro-maven-plugin), I end up with :

- The `Status` class (seems ok)
- The `java.awt.Point` in [a new Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2aAb.png), generated with Avro. It is this one that is referenced in the `Status` class

The Point package does not include any fields that the core package contains (ie. `double x` and `double y`).

A few questions :

- Is there a way to exclude java core package from Avro class generation ? (I want to use the original package, not a generated one)
- If not, how do you assign the `Point` fields in the `Status` generated class ? (`put(String field, Object value)` ?)

Edit : Note that it behaves similarly with `java.awt.Polygon` and `java.sql.Timestamp` (and I'm sure other classes from java core package would too)

Comment: Avro is meant to be used across more than just Java, so this is working as intended and classes outside of `java.lang` and `java.util` and `java.time` generally shouldn't be used

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I haven't seen this anywhere else. Should I convert my objects to primitive values and/or classes from these three packages ?

Comment: Any timestamps can simply be strings or longs, and I don't see anything wrong with having a simple Avro object with x, y fields for a Point record. Also, I almost exclusively use Avro IDL rather than AVSC, which makes it easier to separate out different record types

Comment: That's absolutely what I was planning to do. Hopefully I won't have to deal with more  complex objects with Avro, but at least I got a fix. Thanks for the help :)